# Saving structure in a binary file and reading only value in C++

Tags: c++, structure, binaryfiles

I am studying binary file in c++ nowadays. I have a question about reading and writing structure or class in binary file. For example if I have a structure like,

```
struct A {
    char a1;
    int a2;
    double a3;
};
```

And then I can save a structure with the code like,

```
A a = {'a', 2, 3.5};
ofstream file;
file.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
file.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
file.close();
```

The question is, can I read not the whole structure, but only the value in the structure? For example, If I want to read the integer value of the structure, then,

```
ifstream file;
int i = 1;
file.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
file.seekg(sizeof(char), ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
file.close();
```

Is this possible? If it is not, is there any way to read only one value of the structure?

Comment: the structure isn't aligned, so you should align it,

Comment: There's padding between structure members. `a2` is at an offset 4 from the beginning of the structure, not offset 1 as you assume. Make it `file.seekg(offsetof(A, a2), ios::beg);`. Though it'd likely be easier to just read the whole structure, after all.

Comment: Binary files are usually platform dependent.  Research "Endianess".  Also, pointers are not portable, especially between invocations of the same executable.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ serialization".  The storing of data structures to external media is covered under the top of *serialization*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my binary portability material to get the general idea about binary files and their problems.

It's a bad idea to fwrite an entire structure to disk, even if you plan to just read it in again in the same program. But should you do so, you create a binary image on disk. You can document that. It will consist of char bytes, big or little endian integers of various sizes, pointers (totally useless to you), and doubles and floats for the floating point types.

Once you know the format, you can read it in portably. It's slightly tricky to do that for integers whilst avoiding arithmetical overflow. It is very difficult for floating point values. However the site has code that will allow you to read floating point data portably.

An fwrite() followed by an fread() will work, until the compiler changes its structure layout policy. But that's ahppening all the time at the moment due to the shift to 64 bits.

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/ieee754